# Are there easy ways to sort mongodb collection by reference document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with handling mongodb in nodejs.

Are there any easy ways to sort mongodb collection by reference document in mongoose?

When I need to sort mongodb documents by reference document, it is not easy.

Querying all documents and sort or using mongodb aggregation is complex.

When it is changing sorting field, I should rewrite all query.

Let me know easy ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) for providing options to populate field. In the options, you can pass a sort by fieldname.